# How do I get a Tascam US-122L working?

Tags: sound, drivers

I have [tascam US-122L](http://tascam.com/product/us-122l/) since Windows is really crappy with this, I decided to try linux and ubuntu to be specific..

I tried searching different forums and sites on how to make my US-122L work, but most of the link and site that teaches how to make it work are really out dated.. and I cant get myself to trust a tutorial that is published 2009 and last edited early 2010..

does anyone know how to make my Tascam US122L work? if not just give a link on how to make it work.. atleast from someone who is using and made work on theirs.

Answer (score 1):

I got mine to show up as an alsa device w/11.10 on a Dell inspiron 1525 (pretty much stock) with the following protocol:

Follow the Mediabunto repository instructions:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu

Specifically, use this command:

```
sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update
```

once that's completed execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

`sudo apt-get upgrade` (say yes, this will update your system, may take a bit)

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-firmware
```

At this point, plug in the US-122 and it should be detected by the system and the drivers loaded.

You know it worked right when you execute:

```
cat /proc/asound/modules
```

and there is a line in there referring to `snd_usb_usx2y`

however ymmv, i can address this in Jack (and record to Rosegarden fine) but when using alsamixer and selecting the Tascam device, it claims there are no settings available.

Comment: The first command is outdated and breaks `sudo apt-get update`; had to run `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, wrong answer.

Answer works for the US-122 but the Question was asked about the US122L. The Model name only differs one Letter but the hardware is NOT the same according the Ardour forum https://community.ardour.org/node/1629

The suggested installation on that forum also seems to be out dated. http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~smimram/tascam/ At least it does not seem to work for Ubuntu 14.04 64bit machines. 3.13.0-66 (will try another kernel tomorrow)  in dmesg I can see it is detected, but in the sound panel the settings are not added. So there is clearly something not right.

On Linux music forum it is suggested to use the Arch Linux kernel

Answer (score 0):

the US-122L (the L-version) Still fails to show in Ubuntu
I've been trying to get this device running many times butnever hadany luck to get it to play sound.

In Ubuntu it 20.04 Kernel Linux 5.15.0-60-generic x86_6 it is detected

Alsa firmware is loaded but interface doesn't work

```
$ cat /proc/asound/modules 

 0 snd_hda_intel
 1 snd_usb_us122l
29 thinkpad_acpi

$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 110: ID 0644:800e TEAC Corp. TASCAM US-122L
```

But that's about all. In Pulseaudio it doesn't show up, Neither in VLC.

US-122 (Blue)
US-122L (White)
US-122mkII (Black)
US-144 (Black 5 pots)